# Какой смысл в символе "Т" в стандартном формате записи даты-времени?

Tags: дата, время, любой-язык, стандарт

Какой смысл в символе "Т", например, вот в такой записи даты/времени: 2017-12-27T12:59:04.723 ?

Comment: Зря минусы и зря удаление. Вопрос хороший.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб но метка явно не та

Comment: @andreymal, вы можете поставить правильную)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не уверен, какая будет правильной, так что воздержусь)

Comment: @andreymal, проставил первые попавшиеся на глаза)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Символ `T` - это разделитель даты и времени в строке, описывающий время. Определён в стандарте [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). См. раздел `Combined date and time representations`

Comment: подозреваю, что он означает "time"

Answer (score 11):

Добавлю к ответу @ЮрийСПб:

Стандарт ISO 8601, составлен таким образом, что:

1. Строка даты-времени сплошная без пробельных разделителей
2. Латинские символы используются в качестве разделителей/идентификаторов: `D` - дни, `Y` - годы, `Z` - идентификатор UTC и т.д., например можно задать промежуток времени: `P4Y3M2D1H` - 4 года, 3 месяца, 2 дня и 1 час.

Буква `T` выбрана в качестве уникального разделителя времени, остальные буквы латинского алфавита (почти все) задействованы под разные цели и они не пересекаются. Соответственно упрощается парсинг ISO-8601 строки: имеется заранее известный набор флагов/символов/маркеров, опираясь на которые, можно достаточно быстро разбить строку на нужные составляющие и при этом сохраняется требование к *human readability* самой строки.